# Please explain the answer of a joke: "hors d'oeuvre"

Tags: etymology, british-english, humor

This was part of the Uxbridge English Dictionary part of ISIHAC (I'm sorry I haven't a clue). The word was 'hors d'oeuvre' and the definition was 'ladies who hang around diesel pumps'. I don't get it.

Comment: I don't get it either, but "hor" sounds like "whore," at least in my dialect. That's the "ladies" bit, at least.

Comment: DERV = Diesel-Engined Road Vehicle, so: "Whore DERV"

Comment: Yeah, that's a real groaner.

Comment: @Andrew You have excellent taste, sir. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Hors d'oeuvre" is a pun on "whore DERV". *Whore* is fairly obvious, and DERV is a [UK] acronym for "Diesel-Engined Road Vehicle". In the UK, when diesel cars were uncommon, diesel fuel pumps for lorries (trucks) used to be labelled DERV.

Actually, the pun is the other way round. Never mind.